# How to remove the gpg signature from a signed file without creating a new file on disk?

Tags: linux, security, encryption, pgp

If I have a 100 MB signed binary file that I download over the internet, I need 200 MB of disk space to open it. The file is just signed, not encrypted.

When disk space is low, It is not possible to get the original file as gpg command fails. I saw that the signed gpg file is the original file + some bytes of signature at the beginning and the end. Is it possible to strip these bytes from the file without creating a new file, hence saving disk space ? The signature can be verified using :

```
# gpg --verify filename.gpg
```

without creating a new file on disk. A sample workflow is described below :

```
# # Sample workflow
# cd /tmp/new
# wget http://someaddress/filename.gpg
# ls
filename.gpg
# du -h filename.gpg
100M filename.gpg
# gpg filename.gpg
gpg: Signature made Thu May 28 10:53:26 2015 UTC using RSA key ID XXXXXXXXX
gpg: Good signature from "Example <example@example.com>"
# ls
filename filename.gpg
# du -ch *
100M filename
100M filename.gpg
200M total
# rm filename.gpg
```

When disk space is low, gpg filename.gpg command will fail.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine download process and check the signature in one piped process like this:

```
wget -qO- http://someaddress/filename.gpg|gpg >filename
```

Comment: So this effectively redirects to file to stdout (using RAM) instead of hard disk space ?

Comment: This works for small files, but fails for files > 100 MB :
curl: (18) transfer closed with 89839462 bytes remaining to read

gpg: invalid marker packet
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=76)

Comment: Not exactly, this create pipes and send to the pipe the output from wget and on the same time use it as input for gpg. Yes, there is some amount of RAM,  used for the operation, but not 100MB. About other error you have problem with connectivity. If connection broke you will need to use local file and use curl/wget to get entire file

Comment: Thanks but will still run into some limits due to pipe usage.

Comment: @ElisonNiven I don't think so. A pipe is a queue of bytes, and doesn't need to contain the whole file. There is a limit on the queue length, but when the queue is full the sending process just blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can strip bytes from the beginning and the end without using more disk space. Most utilities, however, will copy the file to a new file, delete the old one, and then rename the new one to be the same as the old one. I think it's safe to assume `gpg` is in this category. This uses double the disk space needed by the file, of course.

What you need to do is:

1. In-place move the bytes of the file "down" by the size of the PGP
   header
2. Set the file's length to remove the PGP trailer

With the right utility, it would even be possible to do this in a single step, and one could easily write a C program to do just this.

However, I assume you want to do it with just the tools already available. It is in fact possible to do this with `dd`:

```
dd if=filename.gpg of=filename.gpg bs=49 skip=1 conv=notrunc
```

This is on the assumption that the header is 49 bytes long. (YMMV)

Now you need to truncate the file to the correct length. There's a utility called `truncate` in GNU `coreutils` that will be present on many Unix systems. However, you need to know the byte offset of the trailer. This can be done with GNU `grep`:

```
grep -b '^-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----' filename.gpg
```

This will output something like:

```
104857600:-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

The final step is to use this value with `truncate`:

```
truncate -s 104857600 filename.gpg
```

However, if you know the length of the trailer already, you can skip the `grep` and just tell `truncate` to shorten the file by that number of bytes:

```
truncate -s -103 filename.gpg
```